# CSS and JS External Linking Server Deployment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I am using twitter bootstrap and foundation (zurb) for two demo single column pages. I can test theme easily on my local machine but I can't get to detect the stylesheet and js file on my own server. It is hosted on the hostgator and i am not sure what is causing the problem.

If I am not wrong uploading the directory as it is on server, doesn't have to be any impact on server side hosting, isn't it? I am just uploading the basic html page example from bootstrap website with minor changes on the text content side.

So

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

this css file reference should be fetched after the server deployment as well.  I also tried using the ../ and using the website URL.

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

I don't know what is going wrong here because on server side i can get the text content visible but not the css and js parsing.

All the three methods of linking to external css or js are wrong? What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried reaching the css file directly via browser?

Comment: Yes. it works with direct URl but i can't seem to use the css and js on the template.

Comment: Could be something with the file permissions.

Comment: @marko-francekovic If it is reachable in the browser directly, then it is not an issue with permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

use the path from the root of the site

> /css/bootstrap.min.css

and close the `<link />` element with `/>`

Comment: Same problem.Stylesheet and JS are not fetched.

Comment: Do you have a URL to see the problem in action?  The JS reference would look different, you're using something like `<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` for that right?

Comment: you can check sparxengine.net for the demo of this problem. Yes. I actually just used the Zurb's simple template to test the problem again and I got the missing stylesheet issue.

Comment: `http://sparxengine.net/css/bootstrap.min.css` is a 404 not found, seems to be a file structure issue.  Have you FTP'd in or how are you uploading your stylesheets/javascript?

Comment: you've got `http://sparxengine.net/css/bootstrap.min.css` working, no longer a 404 error.  The `<link />` reference should work now as well

Comment: I tried as per you described in reply. Just couldn't get it to work. I also checked the file permissions and didn't found any issue.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed the permission issue or file structure, but the HTML [http://sparxengine.net/](http://sparxengine.net/) is currently referencing `/assets/css/bootstrap.css` instead it needs to point to `/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Thanks it seems the examples and the bootstrap code is not updated to the latest build. I just fixed it. I wonder if it was the same issue with the ZURB foundation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have seen the example, I can say it is definitely a problem with the path to the css file.  I confirmed by fixing in DOM inspector.

You can upload your css to here:

`http://sparxengine.net/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

Or you can change the HTML template to reference this file already uploaded:

`http://sparxengine.net/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: I just uploaded the basic example from the zurb as well as the bootstrap and problem persists. My demo site is on sparxengine.net

Comment: Okay, Seems that your page here:
http://sparxengine.net/ is referencing this stylesheet: http://sparxengine.net/assets/css/bootstrap.css, but the actual stylesheet is http://sparxengine.net/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: It was problem with the file permission for some odd reason changing the file permission enabled the access to the css and js file. file permissions were auto reset to the 644 and i can't enable them to 777 so just fixed it on 755 which is safe imo. It's fixed.

Comment: Cool, you also fixed the path to be `/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: I think the examples from the Zurb and bootstrap don't match with the set of files being distributed by the downloader.